# SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column users.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have some problem with group by and having in same query query

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id
     FROM users
     GROUP BY firstname
     HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Getting this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'roag.org.users.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE firstname IN
    (SELECT firstname
     FROM users
     GROUP BY firstname
     HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

The reason you get the error is because of the sub query

```
SELECT id
     FROM users
     GROUP BY firstname
     HAVING count(*) > 1
```

You are selecting id yet its not included in the group by clause. If you group by id I'm sure you wont get the desired result so group by firstname *(and select firstname as well)*

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `*` since you have already use `group by`. If you table like the following :

```
a | b | c | d
```

You you should can group by a:

```
select a, sum(b), max(c), min(d) group by a;
```

Think about that, if you `group` but no sure which field you aggregation, and how can you make the `MySQL` know you what you want it to understand ? so here just make sure what you really want to do, before aggregation by `group`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you were misusing the notorious MySQL GROUP BY extension in an older version of MySQL. They disabled it by default in the current version, with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Your subquery is the problem. It looks like you are trying to find all rows with duplicate `firstname` fields.  You should do this.

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE firstname IN
        (SELECT firstname
           FROM users
       GROUP BY firstname
         HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Why? Because  `SELECT id FROM users GROUP BY firstname` returns `id`, which is *is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause.*  Aggregation isn't quite as magical as we all wish it were.

Answer (score 0):

`ANY_VALUE()` is your friend:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN
   (SELECT ANY_VALUE(id)
    FROM users
    GROUP BY firstname
    HAVING count(*) > 1)
```